# Inconsistencies with relative file paths in JavaScript files

Tags: javascript

The folder structure of the local version site is the exact same as it is on my server, yet I have to change the paths in one of my JS files from:

```
url: "includes/user_process.php" // testing
```

to

```
url: "../includes/user_process.php" // live
```

These are part of an AJAX call. The live version URL makes sense to me, as the directory structure contains a JS folder and an includes folder--so you'd move up one folder w/ '..' and into includes. My PHP files work consistently from development to deployment using the same directory paths.

Having to change the file every time I deploy is pretty irritating and I'm sure it's something simple I'm not picking up on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell, but a quick fix would be to use absolute paths, i.e. `/includes/user_process.php`

Comment: give us an overview of your folder structure (screenshot), and a larger piece of code, with the name of the file it's in (a file that is also showing in the screenshot of the folder structure)... thatn we can gat our juices flowing